# Installing drivers on a Linux Kernel I compiled

Tags: drivers, kernel

I compiled the Linux Kernel following [this](https://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild) tutorial. The tutorial says to first install the necessary tools using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev gcc make git exuberant-ctags bc libssl-dev
```

Then to get a configure script. You can either configure the kernel by yourself, use the default configuration, or copy the configuration file from your system's /boot folder. I chose the last option:

```
cp /boot/config-4.12.0 linux-4.11.10/.config
```

Then compile and install:

```
make
make modules_install install
```

I rebooted into the new kernel and everything seems to be  working. There is, however, one problem. When I try to install a driver, specifically [rtl8812au](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au), it doesn't work. I run make and here is what happens:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.11.10/build M=/home/isaac/rtl8812au  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/isaac/Downloads/linux-4.11.10'
  CC [M]  /home/isaac/rtl8812au/core/rtw_cmd.o
In file included from /home/isaac/rtl8812au/include/drv_types.h:32:0,
                 from /home/isaac/rtl8812au/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/home/isaac/rtl8812au/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘thread_enter’:
/home/isaac/rtl8812au/include/osdep_service.h:251:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘allow_signal’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  allow_signal(SIGTERM);
  ^
/home/isaac/rtl8812au/include/osdep_service.h: In function ‘flush_signals_thread’:
/home/isaac/rtl8812au/include/osdep_service.h:261:6: error: implicit declaration of function ‘signal_pending’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (signal_pending (current)) 
      ^
/home/isaac/rtl8812au/include/osdep_service.h:263:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘flush_signals’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   flush_signals(current);
   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/home/isaac/rtl8812au/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/isaac/rtl8812au/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1492: recipe for target '_module_/home/isaac/rtl8812au' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/isaac/rtl8812au] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/isaac/Downloads/linux-4.11.10'
Makefile:1052: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

On the kernel that comes with my distro (Ubuntu) this always works. It seems like this kernel is missing something. But what, and how can I fill it in?

**Update:** I tried compiling Linux kernel 4.4 and found that the rtl8812au driver compiles on it. So the problem seems to be the newer kernel, not the compilation process. I thank pilot6 and bodhi.zazen for pointing that out in the comments (although version 4.4 is higher than 3.10. So it does work on versions higher than 3.10, just not ones as high as 4.11 or 4.12).

Also, I found that if I configured the kernel with `make localmodconfig` while not running the driver, I couldn't install the driver on the compiled kernel. The driver would build, but then `make install` would fail with an error that a certain directory doesn't exist. And if I create it, `modprobe` would fail.

In any case, I think the reason for this is because `make localmodconfig` looks at what modules are currently in use and only builds those. If a given driver is not in use/not installed the kernel won't be configured for it, which means you can't install it later. So if you plan on installing drivers that you are not currently using/don't currently have installed, you should just copy your system's configuration file. (Someone should correct me if I'm wrong on this.)

Comment: This driver is not supposed to compile with this kernel. It needs to be patched.

Comment: First, when compiling a kernel, use localmodconfig rather then copying an old config. `make localmodconfig`. - use lsmod to examine what modules are currently in use, and thenThis will write your .config to build only those modules. The result is a shorter compilation time and a kernel and modules specific to your hardware.

Comment: Second , in the README "The current rtl8812au version (per nov. 20th 2013) doesn't compile on Linux kernels >= 3.10 due to a change in the proc entry API, specifically the deprecation of the create_proc_entry() and create_proc_read_entry() functions in favor of the new proc_create() function." so you will need a patch or a more modern driver. git hub has a few but I am not sure of your hardware or which one you need.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Isn't that a fork of the rtl8812au driver altered to compile on later kernels? I recall compiling the driver on 4.x kernels that come by default with Ubuntu and other distributions. I think it was the version from that github page, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I am not sure. If it does not compile you would need to file a bug report with the maintainer. FWIW you do not need to run a custom kernel to compile this driver and the driver may be available via a ppa.

Comment: Use modprobe to implement the new drivers. `sudo modprobe -r rtl8821ae` and `sudo modprobe rtl8821ae`.